# django group by another field

Tags: sql, django, group-by

Hey, I want to make a query that will give me the same as this in SQL:

```
select testresult.*,max(timeEnd) 
from testresult 
group by testresult.idTest
```

`idTest` is not PK in testresult.
it is FK in `test`

the need is for the maximal `testresult` for any test
let's say

```
s=query()
s[0].id       ;is that TestResult
```

Comment: You want row with maximum `timeEnd`?

Comment: @DrTyrsa grouped by Tests yeah

Comment: @shevski You'll get it with query in my answer.

Comment: @DrTyrsa I've tried it and values retrives `dict` of `{idTest,maxtimeend}` and I can't refer to testresult from it

Comment: @shevski `testresult` is table name in your query, how do you want to refer to it?

Answer (score -1):

You can group by any field, not only by primary key.

```
TestResult.objects.values('idTest').annotate(max_time_end=Max('timeEnd')).order_by()
```

Comment: how do I get TestResult's PK afterwards?

Comment: that query will get me `dict` of keys for tests and their maximal `timeEnd`

Comment: @shevski And what do you want?

Comment: `Max` is in `django.db.models`, just in case anyone happens upon this and doesn't know. @DrTyrsa: for completeness you should notate any imports required; it's not always easy for a newbie to find that info.